Remove redirect parameter from URL
I have a Sveltekit app that does a bunch of authentication to allow the user to login.
Throughout the login process..some params are visible in the URL for a few seconds. These params prob are related to auth tokens. How can I obfuscate them from the user?

Don't bother: if they exist at all the user can trivially capture them if they want by logging their network activity. As long as you're on https, and you didn't roll your own auth, the auth solution itself should already be resilient enough.

To be sure, tell us more about your solutions. Sometimes, having params that don't need to be params can be an unnecessary risk. For example, maybe the server logs the URL:s of all requests it receives, and if the URL contains sensitive or secret information, then that is logged too, which can be bad.
